# Two absolute position navbar with horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

I'am trying to accomplish the following:

I have two nav bars at the top of the page, which are both absolutely positioned.
I want the second nav bar (#scroll-menu) to have dynamic number of entries and have horizontal scroll.

In this fiddle I made an example of what I want, but without using position absolute: https://jsfiddle.net/cz2xhzjg/3/

```
<div id="main">
<div id="top-menu">
    <div>some content on this bar</div>    
</div>
<div id="scroll-menu">
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
        <li>Six</li>
        <li>Seven</li>
        <li>Eight</li>
        <li>Nine</li>
        <li>Ten</li>
        <li>Eleven</li>
        <li>Twelve</li>
        <li>Thirteen</li>
        <li>Fourteen</li>
        <li>Fifteen</li>
        <li>Sixteen</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<img src="http://www.h3dwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Landscape-wallpapers-1.jpeg" style="width:100%;"/>
```

```
#main {
    width: 300px;
}

#top-menu {
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(244,244,244,0.75);
}

#scroll-menu {
    top: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #bfcfa7;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

li {
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
li:hover {
    color: white;
}
ul {
    width: 900px;
}
```

In this fiddle I have the position absolute and can't make it to have horizontal scroll on the #scroll-menu navbar: https://jsfiddle.net/yxya6qv9/2/

I need the bars to be absolute because the content of the site must appear behind the nav bars.

Thanks.

Comment: Those fiddles look the same to me.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://jsfiddle.net/8f328q5y/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ul {
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/brrqxd5b/

Comment: Applying overflow-x:auto; to the #scroll-menu will create also a vertical scrollbar. Instead like Ege Ozcan pointed out it's better to apply it to the ul element.

Comment: I have also commented on my other answer which you downvoted. Read that link and document yourself before downvoting! :)

Comment: Thanks, both answers, yours and @Ege, are correct. I updated your fiddle so that it has a long list of items in navbar to understand better the purpose http://jsfiddle.net/brrqxd5b/1/